# Read memory mapped file

Tags: java, file, memory

I have to read a memory mapped file, writing seems to work but I don't know how to properly read it. This is how I write the file:

```
public static void writeMapped(ArrayList<Edge> edges) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    // Create file object
    File file = new File("data.txt");

    //Delete the file; we will create a new file
    file.delete();

    // Get file channel in readonly mode
    FileChannel fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();
    // Get direct byte buffer access using channel.map() operation
    // 7 values * 8 bytes(double = 8byte) 
    MappedByteBuffer buffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, (7*8)*edges.size());

    //Write the content using put methods
    for(Edge e : edges){
        buffer.putDouble(e.X1);
        buffer.putDouble(e.Y1);
        buffer.putDouble(e.X2);
        buffer.putDouble(e.Y2);
        buffer.putDouble(e.color.getHue());           
    }

    System.out.print("mapped done!");
 }
```

I have to read the file and create the exact same arraylist as I had when I wrote the file.

Comment: This is home work for students that we are currently teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something along those lines, though it may need some polishing :

```
File file =  new File("data.txt");

FileChannel fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r").getChannel();

MappedByteBuffer buffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fileChannel.size());

List<Edge> edges= new ArrayList<Edge>();

while(buffer.hasRemaining())
{
    Edge e = new Edge();
    e.X1 = buffer.getDouble();
    e.Y1 = buffer.getDouble();
    e.X2 = buffer.getDouble();
    e.Y2 = buffer.getDouble();
    // here you will need to set the color Object first !!
    // e.color.setHue(buffer.getDouble());

    edges.add(e);

}
```